# How do i get information about the window that has focus on Linux using Mono C#

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I already developed an C# .NET WindowsForms application using the Windows user component (user32.dll) that saves the title of the active window (the window that has focus) every time the user changes focus.

Now I'm planning to do the same using Mono C# on Linux. Is it possible?

If yes, for what I'm looking for?

Comment: What do you have thus far in regards to where you state `I am developing an Application` have you started any actual code..? what have you tried

Comment: No. I already have an application that runs on windows and I'am trying to find a way to do the same on Linux.

There I'm using the Windows user component (user32.dll) to get the information.

Comment: I am afraid this depends on window manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take a look at the source of `gnome-screenshot` which has a feature like this (to take a screenshot of the active window, only):

```
static GdkWindow *
screenshot_find_active_window (void)
{
  GdkWindow *window;
  GdkScreen *default_screen;

  default_screen = gdk_screen_get_default ();
  window = gdk_screen_get_active_window (default_screen);

  return window;
}
```

It has some logic to fallback to 'the window under the mouse pointer' when the above returns nothing:

```
GdkWindow *
do_find_current_window (void)
{
  GdkWindow *current_window;
  GdkDeviceManager *manager;
  GdkDevice *device;

  current_window = screenshot_find_active_window ();
  manager = gdk_display_get_device_manager (gdk_display_get_default ());
  device = gdk_device_manager_get_client_pointer (manager);

  /* If there's no active window, we fall back to returning the
   * window that the cursor is in.
   */
  if (!current_window)
    current_window = gdk_device_get_window_at_position (device, NULL, NULL);

  if (current_window)
    {
      if (screenshot_window_is_desktop (current_window))
    /* if the current window is the desktop (e.g. nautilus), we
     * return NULL, as getting the whole screen makes more sense.
         */
        return NULL;

      /* Once we have a window, we take the toplevel ancestor. */
      current_window = gdk_window_get_toplevel (current_window);
    }

  return current_window;
}
```

All of the above depends exclusive on libgdk-pixbuf as far as I can tell. If that's not an option, you could always look at the implementation of those functions in the source of Gdk.

Comment: @AlfredoCavalcanti Wait. You _are_ aware of the fact the Gdk library is supported in Mono? Right?

Comment: I'm very sorry about this @sehe. I had not understood what you meant. Thank you!

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you so much!